# AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:

Tags: objective-c, crash, avcapturedevice

MacOS 10.14

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Record audio!</string>
```

This works in a swift project:

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio) { granted in
            if granted {
                //self.setupCaptureSession()
            }
        }
```

But this does not work in an ObjectiveC project (Thread 8: signal SIGABRT)

```
[AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
            if (granted) {
                //self.microphoneConsentState = PrivacyConsentStateGranted;
            }
            else {
                //self.microphoneConsentState = PrivacyConsentStateDenied;
            }
        }];
```

What have I done wrong or missed in the ObjectiveC project? (I don't want to convert my project to swift.)

Any help appreciated. Thanks, paul

Answer (score 0):

In Order to use the AVCaptureDevice you need to add the description for both items i.e `NSCameraUsageDescription, NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`

For Reference Please see the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624584-requestaccessformediatype)

If you only want to record the Audio you can also use the AVAudioSession API.

Comment: Nope, Swift works with only the mic usage. ObjectiveC still crashes even after I added the camera usage.

Answer (score 0):

I began a new ObjectiveC project (MacOs 10.14) and copied everything from the old project to it (xibs etc). It displayed the appropriate access dialogue but didn't actually record. Had to check the audio input checkbox in capabilities -  after messing about for an hour. :-)